# Add multiple sub-report in single detail section without overlap

Tags: crystal-reports, overlapping, subreport

**Avoid sub report overlap**

1. In crystal report have three sub-report one by one so it can overlap one another.
2. I don't need each sub report in different section.
3. I need each sub report in single detail section without overlap.

Example:

```
-------------------Detail section--------------------------------    
    -------------Sub Report One--------------------  
    -------------Sub Report Two--------------------  
-------------------End of detail section---------------
```

Comment: Please explain why you don't want to use separate sections and why overlapping is important.

Comment: Question doesn't ask for overlapping but overlap not required.... though in single section.

Answer (score -1):

To my extent I know it is not possible...

Though you are not intrested but taking sub reports in individual sections is suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i will try to find solution